# PHP strtotime Issue with date differences

Tags: php, strtotime, date-math

Anyone can explain me what is wrong with strtotime function in this example? I'm trying to count differences between dates. PHP 5.6.0 (cli) (built: Aug 28 2014 08:03:51)
When i execute this loop it displays number 88 twice.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
    $daysAfterTime = floor( abs( strtotime('2014-01-01') - strtotime('2014-01-01 +'.$i.' days')  )/(60*60*24));
    echo $daysAfterTime.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the expected result is, but I would recommend using DateTime class to find time differences.

Comment: ^ [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 5):

`strtotime()` is not intended for date math. [The manual even says so](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

> Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable.

Days are not exactly `60*60*24` seconds long, etc.

As mentioned in the comments `DateTime()` is *much* better suited for this as it accounts for things like daylight savings time, leap year, etc. Here's an advanced way of performing the same operation using [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), and [`DatePeriod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) that is also clearer to anyone trying to figure out what's going on.

```
$start    = new DateTimeImmutable('2014-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$finish   = $start->modify('+101 days'); // extra day as the last day is not inclusive
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');     // interval of one day 
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $finish);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $diff = $start->diff($date);
    echo $diff->days . "<br>";
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/191035)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whats the expected output but the other 88 result is because of that `floor()` function. It rounded the lowest value thus the 88 repeated. Switch the growing value minus the constant value instead so that you don't need to use `abs()` and use `ceil()`.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
    $daysAfterTime = ceil((strtotime('2014-01-01 +'.$i.' days') - strtotime('2014-01-01'))/(60*60*24));
    echo $daysAfterTime.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo (strtotime('2014-01-01 +89 days') - strtotime('2014-01-01 +88 days'))/(60*60), ' hours per day';
// 23 hours per day
```

I think that Europe/London timezone uses [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)

Info about DST of London: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london

```
var_dump(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2014-01-01 +88 days')));
// string(10) "2014-03-30"
```

P.S.
Using [date](http://php.net/date) with z works as expected.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
    $daysAfterTime = date('z', strtotime('2014-01-01 +'.$i.' days')) - date('z', strtotime('2014-01-01'));
    echo $daysAfterTime.PHP_EOL;
}
```